# How to type parameters of a function exposed in a TypeScript library consumed by JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a library written in Typescript which expose a class with a constructor that accept one parameter of type `Set`.

This library will be used by a application written in javascript, I need to check that the parameter is a valid `Set`. My code currently looks something like that:

```js
export class Something {
  private mySet: Set<string>;

  constructor(aSet: Set<string>) {
    if (!(aSet instanceof Set)) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid parameter');
    }

    this.mySet = aSet;
  }
}
```

I created a test suite that checks this code:

```
it('should throw if instantiate without parameter', () => {
  expect(() => {
      new Something();
  }).toThrow();
});

it('should not throw if parameter is a Set', () => {
  expect(() => {
      new Something(new Set([1, 2]));
  }).not.toThrow();
});
```

The Typescript compiler rightfully shown an `error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0` on the first test.

The only way I found to fix this issue is to change the constructor signature and declare my parameter as optional with type `any`, but it doesn't feel right...

```
export class Something {
  private mySet: Set<string>;

  constructor(aSet?: any) {
    if (!(aSet instanceof Set)) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid parameter');
    }

    this.mySet = aSet;
  }
}
```

Is it the proper approach or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the parameter shouldn't be made optional to make tests pass, this defies the purpose of strict typing.

A function should be [asserted with another type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) if it's not used like intended:

```
  expect(() => {
      new (<any>Something)();
  }).toThrow();
```

Or, more specifically with [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) that throws an error, i.e. returns [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

```
  expect(() => {
      new (<{ new(): never }>Something)();
  }).toThrow();
```

Comment: can you elaborate bit on both syntaxes or add links to documentation? Especially the second one? thanks.

Comment: Added some links. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I think that there are no appropriate approach for solving your problem, unless the TypeScript team have implemented disable compiler error for specific line. This feature is already mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448) but it is still yet to come.

So by now, it's either you sacrifice type-safety or you should just ignore that error thrown by the compiler.